# Edit elements of the RIGHT NOW dashboard in Wordpress Admin

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm customizing the Wordpress Admin site to suite my needs and there are several things I want to remove and customize (menus, etc...).

I noticed on the DashBoard section called 'Right Now' there are several things I don't need there.  For instance the CHANGE THEME button and the wordpress version and theme.  I found in the source `dashboard.php` where these are rendered, but rather than edit the source, can I just make a function that intercepts and changes this so it doesn't render them?

I also want to remove the DISCUSSION section and some of the counts for CATEGORIES, TAGS, and PAGES.

Is there a way to go about this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I think I solved this myself, although I'm not sure correctly.  Using firebug I was able to find the class names and element ID's of the version and CHANGE THEME button and the version and theme

I added this code in my functions.php:

```
function wpc_remove_admin_elements() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
        .versions p {display:none !important;}
        .versions #wp-version-message {display:none !important;}
    </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'wpc_remove_admin_elements');
```

This added some styling in my header to hide these elements.

Is there a more efficient way to do this or am I going to be ok? I still don't know how to hide some of the Content and Discussion counts in the RightNow dash.